Obtener ruta local de documento word mediante codigo
Estoy programando un componente VSTO y necesito obtener la ruta del documento actual de Word pero la local no de la nube.
Si utilizo la propiedad FullName del objeto document, me trae la de la nube. ¿Conocen otro método, propiedad para obtener la ruta local? Gracias de antemano.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
